# How to make images in local Storage visible in (CodeNameOne) WebComponent?

Tags: codenameone

In my App I downloaded several images using this code:

boolean bResp = Util.downloadUrlToStorage(
                                url,
                                "IwImage_" + idImage + ".png",
                                true
                            );

This works ok.

Now , I need to make these images visible inside webComponent.

How do I write IMG TAG that points to those images?

How can I figure out the url that points to these local image files in my device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storage is invisible to the web UI as they reside in separate spaces. However, you can use data URI to insert arbitrary images into HTML.

You can use the [WebBrowser.createDataURI(byte[],String)](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/WebBrowser.html#createDataURI-byte:A-java.lang.String-) method to generate a URI that you can embed in an `<img>` tag without a problem.

Comment: Very useful resource. Thank you. Works great.